# What are Non-Community Wikis in Stack Exchange and why is it named so?

Tags: support

I am really curious to know about the differences in the names of Community Wiki and Non-Community Wiki prevailing in Stack Exchange.

As I have known about what a Community Wiki is pretty much, I just specifically want to know the existence of Non-community wiki.

1. What is the reason behind its existence?
2. What is the advantage that I get from it?

I have seen the term **Non-Community wiki** in the Badges area.

**Bronze Badge** - 
You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

**Silver Badge** - You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

**Gold Badge** - 
You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Hence so curious.

Comment: There are only Community Wiki posts, no Non-Community Wiki posts exist. Or do you mean *regular* posts? There are *tag* wikis, but that's something entirely different.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: Right, I read that as (Non-Community) Wiki, but I guess the term Non-(Community Wiki) could mean something here. :-)

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Now posted as a feature request: [Change “non-community wiki answers” in tag badge descriptions to something less confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218179/change-non-community-wiki-answers-in-tag-badge-descriptions-to-something-less)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non-Community Wiki is not anything.  In the context you mentioned in the descriptions of the badges, it simply means "A post that is not a Community Wiki".  There is no special Non-CW classification on posts.

For your specific examples (emphasis & parenthesis mine):

> Bronze Badge - You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-**(community wiki)** answers to achieve this badge.

This specifically means you need to have a total score of 100 in 20 answers that are not Community Wiki.  This same definition applies to the other badges.