# Change "non-community wiki" in tag badge descriptions to something less confusing

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, wording

This feature request is inspired by the question [What are Non-Community Wikis in Stack Exchange and why is it named so?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218168/what-are-non-community-wikis-in-stack-exchange-and-why-is-it-named-so), which in turn was caused by confusing wording in the tag badge descriptions:

> "I have seen the term **Non-Community wiki** in the Badges area.
>
> **Bronze Badge** - 
>   You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
>
> **Silver Badge** - You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
>
> **Gold Badge** - 
>   You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge."

Yeah, sure, *we* all know what it's supposed to mean, because we're familiar with SE jargon and know that answers come in two varieties: "normal" and "community wiki".  But for new users unfamiliar with such esoteric details, parsing "non-community wiki answers" as "wiki answers that are non-community, whatever that means" is a perfectly reasonable interpretation of the ambiguous wording.

So let's fix it!  My suggestion for improved wording would be:

> "You must have a total score of *X* in at least *Y* answers (excluding community wikis) to achieve this badge."

If you have an even better suggestion, let's hear it!

Comment: Not only is that less ambiguous, it sounds much better too

Answer (score 10):

I agree, the wording does make it seem like "non-community wiki" is a type of post as the OP of the linked question thought.

I think your wording is sufficiently clear and gets the point across, but since we've already wrapped to another line, let's make use of the extra space and make it as clear as possible (my addition in bold):

> "You must have a total score of X in at least Y answers (excluding **answers marked [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)**) to achieve this badge."

And it would be even better if we would link to the [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question or some other description of Community Wiki posts.

Comment: As a testament to the importance of this change, let me just say that I arrived at this page by googling for "non-community wiki" because I'm newish to Stack Exchange had the same confusion as OP. Your answer helped a lot.